# how save and clean method works in django model class and how they are invoked? Also, how super is helping in this code?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework import serializers
import re
class UserModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, default='')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, default='')
    #phone = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default='')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True, default='')
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)

    **def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.clean()
        return super(UserModel, self).save(**kwargs)**

    **def clean(self):
        super(UserModel, self).clean()**
        errors = {}
        valphone = self.phone
        valmail = self.email
        regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.\w{2,3}$'
        if not (valphone.isdigit() and len(valphone) == 10):
            errors['phone'] = (f"{valphone} must`enter code here` be 10 digits and shouldn't contain any string")
        if not (re.search(regex, valmail)):
            errors['email'] = ('Invalid email id format')
        if errors:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(errors)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clean` by default is not called by `save` meaning you need to call this manually. In the code you have shared, `save` is customised to make sure that `clean` is called every time `save` is called. After calling the clean, it then calls the default `save` method via `super()`

You can read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

> Note, however, that like Model.full_clean(), a model’s clean() method is not invoked when you call your model’s save() method.

Comment: so it means when I invoke save() method from views.py file using POST call then the save method of model class is called right ?

    [elif request.method == 'POST':
        user_data = JSONParser().parse(request) #reference data from model, data is going to be parsed using jsonparser
        user_serializer = UserDataSerializer(data=user_data) #data to be serialized
        if user_serializer.is_valid(): #data to be serialized is valid
            user_serializer.save() #save data]

Comment: You need to show your serializer implementation. But as long as you call the model's save method (not just the serializer save method) it should be fine